# How to return a FileContent with FileReader from function in PhoneGap iOS?

Tags: ios, file, cordova, filereader

If, for example, i will that fileReader must return a content value of file, i get back only empty string. Global variable for me impossible to use, only local.    Is it possible?
What do i wrong?

**Edit:**

```
function onDeviceReady() {    
    console.log("==> DEVICE READY");    
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, fileErrorMSG);    
}    

function onFSSuccess(fs) {    
    fileSystem = fs;    
}    

function readlocalFile(fileName) {    
    var core = "";    

    fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, {create: false}, function(f) {    
        f.file(function(e) {    
            var reader = new FileReader();    
            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {    
                var res =  $.parseJSON(evt.target.result);    
                core = res;    
            };    
            reader.readAsText(e);    
        });//f.file()    
    }, fileErrorMSG);    

    return core;    
}     

function loadDefaultCore(url) {    
    if (url) {    
        var myCore = readlocalFile(url);    
        console.log(myCore); // **output - empty string!!!!!!!!**    
    } else {    
        alert('can not load default core');    
    }    
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there a bunch of things to consider. In brief:

1. First, to read a file you need to get the file system.
2. Second, on success you need to get the file entry using the file system.
3. Third, on success read the file using the file entry.

The three have to be chained via the functions callbacks.

You are getting empty as you file is not being read.
I follow the chain an after the onFSSuccess function the chain is broken, the readLocalFile function is not being called, just add it after you assign your file system to the fileSystem variable which I assume is a global variable. Or call your function loadDefaultCore, I am not sure which one you really want to call first.

It will help you if you add more console log messages in each function so you can actually debug the problem easily.

Also, did you have your document even listener attached to the device ready function?
Any messages, errors warnings in the console?

From the phonegap file api, follow this and you will be safe. Check the doc for the phonegap version you are  working on.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load //function onLoad() { document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); }

// Cordova is ready //function onDeviceReady() { window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail); }

function gotFS(fileSystem) { fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail); }

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) { fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail); }

function gotFile(file){ readDataUrl(file); readAsText(file); }

function readDataUrl(file) { var reader = new FileReader(); reader.onloadend = function(evt) { console.log("Read as data URL"); console.log(evt.target.result); }; reader.readAsDataURL(file); }

function readAsText(file) { var reader = new FileReader(); reader.onloadend = function(evt) { console.log("Read as text"); console.log(evt.target.result); }; reader.readAsText(file); }

function fail(evt) { console.log(evt.target.error.code); }

</script>
```